# Delete rows based on difference in timestamp- spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a spark dataframe that has two columns ("time_stamp" and "ID").

Example dataframe:

```
      **ID**                **time_stamp**
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:23:16
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:54:40
      25CD               2015-01-23 09:02:20
       1AB               2015-01-23 10:15:36
       1AB               2015-01-23 12:38:40
```

I want to remove duplicate IDs (keeping the 1st occurrence) if the timestamp difference is less than 3Hrs from the first occurence (keep ID which appear first) and want to keep IDs if the difference is greater than 3 Hrs.

Expected output:

```
      **ID**                **time_stamp**
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:23:16
      25CD               2015-01-23 09:02:20
       1AB               2015-01-23 12:38:40
```

Thanks

Comment: why is 12:38:40 a separate entry? It's within 3 hours of 10:15:36.

Comment: @mck Edited the question for clarity. 3 Hrs is calculated from the 1st appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spark-sql:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1(
select  '1AB' c1, '2015-01-23 08:23:16' c2 union all 
select  '1AB' c1, '2015-01-23 08:54:40' c2 union all 
select  '25CD' c1, '2015-01-23 09:02:20' c2 union all 
select  '1AB' c1, '2015-01-23 10:15:36' c2 union all 
select  '1AB' c1, '2015-01-23 12:38:40' c2 
) select c1 id, c2 timestamp from t1

""")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("view1")

spark.sql(""" 
select id,timestamp from (
select id, timestamp, unix_timestamp(timestamp)-unix_timestamp(mn)  diff from 
(select id, timestamp, min(timestamp) over(partition by id) mn from view1 ) temp
) temp2 
where  diff=0 or diff > 3*60*60
""").show(false)

+----+-------------------+
|id  |timestamp          |
+----+-------------------+
|1AB |2015-01-23 08:23:16|
|1AB |2015-01-23 12:38:40|
|25CD|2015-01-23 09:02:20|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: which one will have a better peroformance, spark sql or the answer @mck provided?

Comment: sparksql has an advantage as the engine can parse  and analyze better. Anyway, better to test with high volume using 2 approaches and then conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a grouping using the quotient of the time since the beginning of the group divided by 3 hours.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "grouping",
    (
        (F.col("time_stamp").cast("long") - F.first("time_stamp").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time_stamp")).cast("long")) / (3*3600)
    ).cast("int")
).withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ID", "grouping").orderBy("time_stamp")
)
).filter("rn = 1").drop("grouping","rn")

df2.show()
+----+-------------------+
|  ID|         time_stamp|
+----+-------------------+
| 1AB|2015-01-23 08:23:16|
| 1AB|2015-01-23 12:38:40|
|25CD|2015-01-23 09:02:20|
+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Select t.id, t.timestamp, count(id), Timestampdiff(hour,timestamp,  t. Prev_timestamp) Select id, timestamp, LAG(timestamp, 1)  over (partition by id order by id) Prev_timestamp
From table) t
Having count(id)

> 1 and     timestampdiff (HOUR,timestamp, prev_timestamp) >3